# GTM trigger when button is disabled

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have form on my site, where I would like to send people an email reminder, if the form is not completed. 
But I don't want to send the email to people that not meets the requirements. 
So, Is there a way to trigger an event in Google Tag manager, if the button element is getting the class "disabled"?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, 
Right now, I don't have any code in GTM bescause I couldn't find anything that works. 
HTML code look like this: 
<button type="submit" id="submitBtn" disabled="" class="disabled">Send</button>

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding comments, please

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is! You can simply look to see if the Click element HTML contains 'disabled', something like this:

[Google Tag Manager Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EouB8.png)